# Laravel model issue (non-object)

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3 and this model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'slug',
        'description',
        'thumbnail',
        'parent',
        'created_by'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_by'
    ];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public static function getSubcategories($category)
    {
        return Category::whereParent(Category::whereSlug($category)->first()->id)->get();
    }
}
```

It works perfectly on my localhost server, but when I upload it on my production server, it outputs following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object (on line ....)

It is on this line:

```
return Category::whereParent(Category::whereSlug($category)->first()->id)->get();
```

(Lines are hidden, because this model has much more functions and would be too long for this post)

Full trace:
[image: Full error stack trace]

Comment: Does your **production database** have records in the `categories` table?

Comment: @BaikHo I am using same database for localhost and production

Comment: post your complete error stack trace.

Comment: @aimme I have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

its because the `Category::whereSlug($category)->first()` is returning null and that you are trying to get id of that null. so its as the error states that you are trying to get a property of non object.

I see that you are trying to get self reference category. you could so it this way as a relationships.

```
//children
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent');
}

//parent
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent');
}
```

if you want to select recursively you could add this too.

```
public function parentRecursive()
{
    return $this->parent()->with('parentRecursive');
}

public function categoriesRecursive()
{
    return $this->categories()->with('categoriesRecursive');
}
```

Comment: I tried to dd(Category::whereSlug($category)->first()) and there is a result.

Comment: see, that would do what you are trying to achieve @User

Comment: i have tried also your solution but result is the same error. Any idea?